# Call Mage::getModel within jquery script

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute

Looking for some direction as to how I can call

> Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product',
>   'color')->getId()

from within a jquery script like swatches-list.js. Maybe someone has an easy solution? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't <sup>**1**</sup>. One is *PHP* - the other is *Javascript*.

Your best approach (if you need this to be dynamic) is to make an *AJAX call* to a custom controller from within your jquery script to provide the id you need.

If it doesn't need to be dynamic you could initialise a *JS variable* from a *phtml template* that your jquery script reads.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> - At least not without running your js file through the php processor, which is not a good idea